# What is the sense behind Template Type?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, raw-types

By using templates:

```
template <class T>
T GetMax (T a, T b) {
  return (a>b?a:b);
}
```

and then

```
int main () {
  int i=5, j=6, k;
  long l=10, m=5, n;
  k=GetMax(i,j);           // line 1
  n=GetMax<int>(l,m);      // line 2
  n=GetMax<double>(l,m);   // line 3
  cout << k << endl; 
  cout << n << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

my questions are:

why do I need to do this:

```
n=GetMax<int>(l,m);      // line2
```

if I can do

```
n=GetMax(l,m);      // line 2
```

and why this compiles?

```
n=GetMax<double>(l,m);
```

when **l** and **m** are integers which are far away different from a double?

Comment: `why do I need to do this?` : You don't. `why this compiles?` : `T` is instatiated to `long`. `long` is implicitly convertible to `double`. It is the same as doing `double v = m;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context you can think that template instantation is a simple text replacement (It's not that far from it), that is once you have the template parameters figured out. So:

1. You let the compiler figure out the type from the operands. Since they match, `T` is figured out to be `int`. You can find the exact logic of ranking matching template parameters in the standard. Your case is pretty straightforward.

After figuring out template parameter, the substitution is made, so your function looks like:

```
int GetMax (int a, int b) {
   return (a>b?a:b);
}
```

It does get compilcated, when you use multiple parameters and have many possible matches with inheritance etc, etc.

For your case you can provoke equal matches, by using two different types for params i.e: `GetMax(i,l)`. `T` has two candidates: `double` as `int`, and both are equally good.

This is related to the famous SFINAE (substitution failure is not an error). Compiler tries to generate versions for possible parameter combinations, and if it fails, it's not taken for consideration for final ranking. In your case two substitutions were successful.

2. You explicitly state that T is `int`. So the compiler does not invoke automatic parameter matching. The instantiated version looks the same as 1.
3. You explicitly state that T in `double`. Again, the compiler does not invoke any logic regarding the types.

It blindly generates version for `double`, and uses it:

```
 double GetMax (double a, double b) {
    return (a>b?a:b);
 }
```

It's legal to pass an `int` to a function using `double`, an implicit conversion happens.

This is perfectly legal:

```
void f(double d) {};

int main(){
    int i = 5;
    f(i);
}
```

**Bottom line:**

Figuring out template types is a different piece of logic than invoking the function. Think of it as separate phases. Type deduction is designed to make sense for the invocation, but it's a separate thing.

Comment: As a small addition: If the arguments are of different types (eg. `getMax(i,l)`) the automatic type deduction will fail and you will get a compiler error. In that case you need to make the type explicit somehow to make it compile (either by casting the arguments to a common type or by specifying the template type explicitly, like you did in your cases 2 and 3).

Comment: Yes, because there are two possible candidates which are equally good for substitution. I shall edit 1. to mention it.

Comment: is that correct if I ommit the <int> when calling GetMax<int>(a, b) ??

Answer (score 0):

You can omit the types on template functions because they are deducted in compile time

And the second question, there's no error because integers fallbacks gracefully to double, so they will be converted and used as double on your template logic.